# XML Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

How can I use Regex Replace with XML?

Assuming I have the given text below:

```
<test>Hello World</test>
<test1>Hello World</test1>
<test2>Hello World</test2>
<test3>Hellow World</test3>
```

How can I replace all "Hello World" tag values if the parent tag is not `test` tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1726343

Comment: Do you want it to replace it only if the tag value is "Hello World"? Or you want to replace it with a fixed content only if the tag is "test" regardless of the content?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, what I intended to do is change all hello world value if the parent tag is not test...Thanks

Comment: @Default Yes, this is XML, and many of the same rules apply. XML is less fuzzy, but you can't parse it without resorting to things like recursion in your regex, in which case your regex no longer fits in the category of finite automata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Regex` can be used for parsing XML since it is **strict** with its format but it is not **recommended** to use it

Use `LINQ2XML`

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");
foreach(XElement elm in doc.Descendants().Elements().Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName!="test"))
{
     if(elm.Value=="hello World")
          elm.Value="";//replace here
}

doc.Save("yourXml.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Regex` using `negative lookahead` and `negative lookbehind` assertion:

```
(?<!<test>)(Hello World)(?!</test>)
```

explain:

> ***`(?<! subexpression )`***
>   Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.
>
> ***`(?! subexpression )`***
>   Zero-width negative lookahead assertion.

And replace with your string using [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx):

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, "(?<!<test>)(Hello World)(?!</test>)", "New World");
```